# Convert string to numeric and calculate time difference

Tags: r, type-conversion

Can you help me calculate the time difference between 2 consecutive observations in R?

```
2018-03-08T21:40:46.555Z
2018-03-08T21:43:52.492Z
2018-03-08T21:43:52.691Z
2018-03-08T21:48:07.593Z
2018-03-08T21:48:08.729Z
2018-03-08T21:54:59.071Z
2018-03-08T21:54:59.121Z
2018-03-08T21:55:00.636Z
2018-03-08T21:55:00.694Z
```

How can I convert these strings to numeric and do the calculation?

Answer (score 1):

You're looking for two distinct functions in R. The first converts it from a string to a date time, which, for all intents and purposes, is just a number. To do this, you have to specify the format that your string is in. You can do this with `as.POSIXct(my_dates, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')`. This will give you the object back as a `POSIXct` object, which allows us to do "time math" on it. The next step is to calculate the differences. This can be done with the `difftime` function. Since you want it done on consecutive values, you can use `difftime(tail(my_dates, -1), head(my_dates, -1))` to get a vector of differences. The full code is below:

```
> x = c('2018-03-08T21:40:46.555Z', '2018-03-08T21:43:52.492Z', '2018-03-08T21:43:52.691Z', '2018-03-08T21:48:07.593Z', '2018-03-08T21:48:08.729Z', '2018-03-08T21:54:59.071Z', '2018-03-08T21:54:59.121Z', '2018-03-08T21:55:00.636Z', '2018-03-08T21:55:00.694Z')
> y = as.POSIXct(x, format='%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S')
> z = difftime(tail(y, -1), head(x, -1))
> z
Time differences in hours
[1] 21.73111 21.73111 21.80194 21.80222 21.91639 21.91639
[7] 21.91667 21.91667
```

You can get the results in different time units by changing the `units` parameter in `difftime`.

```
> z = difftime(tail(y, -1), head(x, -1), units='days')
> z
Time differences in days
[1] 0.9054630 0.9054630 0.9084144 0.9084259 0.9131829
[6] 0.9131829 0.9131944 0.9131944
```